# View Layer setting do not show up in certain files

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, denoise, viewlayers

*I have no View Layer settings. But in other files I have all these settings. This is in the Cycles Render engine. In the render setting I can't choose my Gpu or Cpu but if I switch to a different file I have all these setting available. I have no way of lowering or raising my samples or using the denoiser. But if I switch to Evee all of these setting work and come up. *[image]